# Networking websockets on node.js servers

Tags: node.js, network-programming, webserver, port

So I've been coding in web design for two weeks now and I've devolved the core for my io game on node.js just by using localhost:3000 now I'm trying to implement what I have so far into an actual web-server. It's one heck of a learning curve, so say I set up a virtual-machine in Google Cloud Platforms running node.js, socket.io what do I even set my ports too?

This is my Code currently server side:

```
var express = require('express'); //adds express library
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(3000); //listens on port 3000
app.use(express.static('public')); //sends the public(client data)
console.log("Server Has Started");
var socket = require('socket.io'); //starts socket 
var io = socket(server);
```

This is my Code currently client side:

```
var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3000")
```

my website is gowar.io and it currently resides as a static file in googles "bucket". How do I hook up my websockets with something like a virtual machine?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, cloud ecosystems will give you an endpoint for your storage or allow you to configure one.

Skim through Google's [Docs about WebSockets](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-websockets-and-session-affinity) to learn more about their recommended implementation of WebSockets.